understanding the integral $\oint_{|z| = 1}z^{-1}dz$
This is a somewhat vague question.
I am aware that the integral in the title can be computed via a parametrization and that its value is $2\pi i$. The $i$ comes from differentiating $\exp(it)$ and the $2\pi$ comes from the arclength of the curve traced along the unit circle.
I am trying to better understand where why the value of the integral is imaginary and $2\pi$ shows up in the modulus. Since there are many other closed contours $\gamma$ enclosing a singularity at the origin whose integral equals $2\pi i$, I suspect the answer I am looking for will involve the geometry of the punctured plane.
An explanation using the residue theorem seems to beg the question.

Per zetko's comment, we can do this:
$$
\begin{align*}
\oint_{|z| = 1}z^{-1}dz &= \oint_{|z| = 1}\bar z\,dz
= \oint_{|z|=1}(x - iy)(dx + i\,dy)\\
&= \oint_{|z| = 1}(x\,dx + y\,dy) + i\oint_{|z| = 1}(x\,dy - y\,dx)\\
&= \iint_{\mathbf D}((y_x - x_y) + i(x_x + y_y))\,dx\wedge dy\\
&= \iint_{\mathbf D}(0 + 2i)\,dx\wedge dy
= 2i\iint_{\mathbf D}\,dx\wedge dy
= 2\pi i.
\end{align*}
$$
I suppose this is what I was after, though I welcome any further thoughts on the matter.

It is unclear what do you expect as an answer beyond something like "because $\pi$ is transcendental."

Then you should edit your question accordingly; also explain if you know the residue theorem and why the answer it gives is insufficient.

You can also convert this integral into $\int_{dK} \bar{z} \cdot dz$, which as a direct consequence of Green's theorem gives $2i \cdot \iint_K \frac{d\bar{z}}{d\bar{z}} \cdot dS = 2\pi i$ (if you want to avoid parametrization and the residue theorem/cauchy's formula).

Timestamp 18:39 of this video here explains how to do the calculations rather than just a direct computation of Cauchy's Integral Formula, but if you have the time, it's better to watch some previous chapters if you want a better understanding.

Your edit arrived while I was preparing this answer, which is similar to what you already have, though in somewhat different words.

First, note that this particular integral is defined over the perimeter of a circle of radius $1$ with center $(0,0)$. That is, $z$ in the integral is a point that moves on the perimeter of this circle. Note especially that the integration path is symmetrical.
Next, note that $z^{-1}$ in this particular problem is the reflection of $z$ with respect to the horizontal axis (why?). The inverse of $z$ is shown as $z'$ in the above figure.
Now, it may help to convert the integral to a cartesian equivalent for a while
$$I = \oint_C (x - iy)(dx + i dy) = \oint_C xdx + \oint_C ydy + i\oint_C (xdy - ydx)$$
where $C$ is the perimeter of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. It is important to note that all the above integrals are taken over a path and not a surface.
Of the three integrals in the right hand side above, the first two are zero because of symmetry (why?). To calculate the third one, I prefer to convert coordinates, this time into polar.
$$x = \cos\alpha \qquad dx = -\sin\alpha \,d\alpha $$
$$y = \sin\alpha \qquad dy = \cos\alpha \,d\alpha $$
$$I = i\int_{\alpha=0}^{2\pi} (\cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha) \,d\alpha $$
$$= 2\pi i $$
